# Zimbra session expires while I type

Tags: session, webmail, zimbra

My institution uses Zimbra (7.1.4_GA_2555) to provide a webmail interface. One problem I have with this system is that it automatically closes (expires) the current session relatively frequently, and more importantly: It does that very often *while* I am writing a mail! I can then log back in, and find most of that email saved as a draft, but often the last sentence or so has been sent to tumbolia. This is extremely annoying.

My questions:

– Is there anything I as a user can do to prevent this, some hidden preference (the overt ones don't help), or something I can configure in my browser (Chrome on Linux) to maybe automatically extend the session periodically?

– Is there a Zimbra server setting that I can ask my admin to adjust? I realize the correct procedure would be that I report the problem to him (which I did) and then he researches a solution – but he didn't, so I gather if I can provide the solution on a silver platter I have a better chance.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I as a user can do to prevent this, some hidden preference (the overt ones don't help), or something I can configure in my browser (Chrome on Linux) to maybe automatically extend the session periodically?

No, that is not possible, it is a security measure that the session times out after some time.

> Is there a Zimbra server setting that I can ask my admin to adjust? I realize the correct procedure would be that I report the problem to him (which I did) and then he researches a solution – but he didn't, so I gather if I can provide the solution on a silver platter I have a better chance.

Here's an excerpt from the relevant [link](http://www.zimbra.com/docs/os/6.0.8/administration_guide/Configuring%20Mailbox%20Features.10.4.html#1075661):

**Auth token lifetime** sets a browser cookie that contains the auth token. User can open ZWC without having to log on again until the auth token expires. The default is 2 days.When it expires, the log in page is displayed and the user must log in to continue.

**Session idle lifetime** sets how long a user session remains active, if no activity occurs. Activity includes any clickable mouse action, such as viewing contents of a folder or clicking a button. The default is 2 days.

It's might also possible that you somehow disallow cookies for the zimbra server, causing weird session behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the information! But this doesn't really relate to the behavior I described, does it? A "session idle" should be reset every time I press a button while writing an email. And I wouldn't expect this behavior from an expired cookie either...